# Is it possible that only surface electrons of the metal wire conduct electricity at light speed

Tags: electricity, metals

Because if drift velocity of electrons is so slow than the actual speed of electricity which is near the speed of light. Then it might be possible that only electrons at the surface of metallic wire move at the speed of light .

Comment: Particles with mass, such as electrons, cannot move at the speed of light.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to understand why the speed of the electrons is not the same as the speed of electricity is to imagine a long thin pipe that we fill with marbles. Push more marbles into one end of the pipe - how quickly after you do so do marbles start popping out of the other end? That's like the speed of electricity, and is very fast. How fast are the marbles in the pipe actually moving? That's like the drift velocity, and is very slow.

Electrons repel one another. If you try to push two together, they resist, like marbles resist being pushed into one another. The forces between the electrons hold them rigidly apart. When you push electrons into one end of the wire, it is the wave of increased repulsive force along the chain of electrons that conveys the force rapidly to the other end. The repulsive force between like charges is caused by electromagnetism, so the energy or force of 'electricity' is actually carried along the wire by an electromagnetic wave.

When you study the maths a lot more deeply, you find that the energy flow in an electromagnetic field can be represented by the *Poynting vector*, and when we calculate the Poynting vector for a wire conducting electricity it turns out that most of the energy is carried in the electromagnetic field *outside* the wire, close to its surface. The electron's repulsive fields spreads out in all directions, even beyond the wire. If you keep switching the direction of the electric current back and forth very fast, the electromagnetic field around the wire carrying the energy also sloshes back and forth, like jelly, causing some of the electricity's energy to spread out from the wire in electromagnetic waves.

None of the electrons need to move very fast individually for all this to happen. If they did, they would rip out of the side of the wire at close to the speed of light whenever the wire turned a sharp corner, or the wire would need to apply huge mechanical forces to make them turn. In the Large Hadron Collider at CERN, they need huge, truck-sized superconducting magnets just to apply the forces needed to get the particles to turn in a circle 8 km across. The LHC is a good example of electricity flowing around a loop the way people commonly *think* it does!

Comment: Note that the energy often flows in the direction opposite the electron flow.

Answer (score 0):

No, because we can solve the actual quantum equations necessary to explain how electrons move in a metal, and know not just the DC motion, but also the AC motion. The former is a bulk movement, and the latter is more concentrated on the surface.

Your suspicion the drift velocity is too slow, turns out to be correct. But the fast motion is nowhere near the speed of light. There is another speed that is rather fast, yet many times slower than the speed of light, that is involved.